# Python - BeautifulSoup4: tag variable getting lost?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get to a div inside a div inside an article tag. Here is my code until it crashes:

```
chart = soup.find('div',{'class':"chart-data"})
for divTag in chart.find_all('div'):
    for articleTag in divTag.find_all('article'):
        savedSpans[1]=str(articleTag.get('id'))[4:]
        print savedSpans[1]
        FirstDiv=articleTag.find("div",{'class':'row-primary'})
        print 'articleTag', type(articleTag)
        print 'FirstDiv', type(FirstDiv)
        SecondDiv=FirstDiv.find("div",{'class':'row-title'})
```

Here is the output. For some reason, before the print 'FirstDiv' line and the SecondDiv= line, the print commands are repeated and the "FirstDiv" variable loses it's value. And ideas?

```
1
articleTag <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
FirstDiv <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>

articleTag <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
FirstDiv <type 'NoneType'>
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "billboardscrape.py", line 26, in <module>
    SecondDiv=FirstDiv.find("div",{'class':'row-title'})
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by being more specific in my tag identifiers:

```
chart = soup.find('div',{'class':"chart-data"})
    for divTag in chart.find_all('div', {'class':"container"}):
        for articleTag in divTag.find_all('article',{'class':"chart-row"}):
            savedSpans[1]=str(articleTag.get('id'))[4:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if the program is crashing we need to see the error statement.

You are looping through all the div elements:

```
for divTag in chart.find_all('div'):
```

For each div element you are looping through all the elements titled 'article'.

```
for articleTag in divTag.find_all('article'):
```

Ok, so articleTag represents the current 'article' tag found in the current Div element being iterated over.

You then set the variable FirstDiv as a search within articleTag for class: row-primary.

It seems like the second articleTag doesn't contain any elements with the class row-primary so the return is None. i.e FirstDiv = None

Then you run the:

```
SecondDiv=FirstDiv.find("div",{'class':'row-title'})
```

This results in an error because as mentioned before FirstDiv is None (i.e not found.

Before running SecondDiv=... you need to check whether FirstDiv is equal to None, if FirstDiv is equal to None you know not to run the .find method on this variable.

Comment: I added the full error message. it's pretty clear that the issue occurs because FirstDiv is none. What is not clear is why the print statements I put for troubleshooting are repeated, with the first set being correct totally correct and the second set having FirstDiv have no type - this is clear in that in the first set, FirstDiv has a bs4 element tag.

Comment: I explained why the print statement is repeated in my answer, the reason is that in the first set of error messages you are looking at a different article tag. (In your script you are looping through all the article tags).